# Why isn't task scheduler working but running rake manually working

Tags: heroku, rake, scheduler

I have an app running on heroku and once an hour I need to run a rake task called get_instagram_photos. I am scraping instagram and then adding the info to the database. If I run the following manually in terminal the task works great.

```
$> heroku run rake get_instagram_photos
```

I am using the new scheduler addon that heroku implemented. I added get_instagram_photos as one of the tasks that I would like to run once an hour. The dashboard seems to tell me that it runs once an hour however I don't see any data being added to the database. I am 100% sure the task works it just seem that something is amiss when I allow scheduler to run it.

How should I begin to trouble shoot this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You actually need to add `rake get_instagram_photos` (Looks like you forgot the `rake`) to your scheduler addon.

You can find more info in the Scheduler doc: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler

Comment: such an important minute detail.

Comment: i've spend more time on this than i'd ever be willing to admit