# Heroku scheduler is not working but running rake manually working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake

I have a task that takes over 45 minutes. It runs successfully with

```
$ heroku run rake:sales
```

I also doublechecked my settings in scheduler based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428765/why-isnt-task-scheduler-working-but-running-rake-manually-working). Everything looks fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In order to prevent run-away jobs, jobs that run longer than their frequency will be terminated. For example, a job that runs every 10 minutes will be terminated after running for 10 minutes.

What's happening is that your rake task is running for the first 10 minutes, but Heroku aborts it after that elapses. They suggest using a [background job queue](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing) for long-running tasks.

Source:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler#long-running-jobs

Comment: This is it. It seemed overkill to wrap a rake task inside a resque task, sort of like double background tasks, but now it makes sense, see my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22388155/does-rake-task-need-to-run-in-the-background-using-resque

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the long-running issue that `@KKobayashi` has alluded to, you may not have the correct rake file created for the scheduler to run:

[Heroku Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler):

> For Rails, the convention is to set up rake tasks. To create your
>   scheduled tasks in Rails, copy the code below into
>   `lib/tasks/scheduler.rake` and customize it to fit your needs

Have you tried putting your tasks into a a `scheduler.rake` file?

Comment: Yes they are in a rake file and my other jobs run successfully, thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you're scheduling the task for an app other than the one you intend to schedule it for.

To check, open the scheduler (heroku addons:open scheduler) and check the url. If you see another app's name in the url, you need to add the scheduler addon again i.e.:

heroku addons:create scheduler:standard

Now open it again (heroku addons:open scheduler)